# Forwarding ports and traffic to VPN tunnel

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn, tcp, port-forwarding

I've installed OpenVPN on my VPS.
I have one question: how to forward traffic going to that VPS to go to VPN tunnel created with my local PC. I will use TCP connection. 
The whole traffic will be like 
Internet -> VPS -> VPN tunnel -> my PC. I think it will use iptables for forwarding, but I dont know if it will work and how it will work. 
The PC have private IP and I dont see any other sollutions.
Its kinda like reverse VPN.

The OpenVPN is fully instaled and its working.

I appreciate all tips :)

Comment: Use the peer IP address used by your VPS to access the VPS from your PC; that's the simple answer. Otherwise you have to supply more info; edit your question and add the output from the following commands, *after* the VPN is established: `ip addr show`; `ip route show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least three possible solutions.

1. Setting up policy based routing on your private PC. (hard to setup, more permanent, pretty)
   http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html
2. Set up ssh port forwarding. (easy, junky solution)
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding
3. Set up destination NAT (PAT) and source NAT @ VPS. (easier than (1), ugly)
   https://thewiringcloset.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/linux-iptable-snat-dnat/